# Using MAN command for describing Documentation of a script

Tags: unix, reference, manpage

I have a sample script in perl.
e.g script.pl
Contents:
print "Hello\n";

I also have a document for the above script as script.doc which describes the script usage and other details.
I want to write MAN command so that it explains the document completely. Using the document as a reference.

Please help.
I am unable to find any lead on the same also I am new to UNIX.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a troff formatted page for the man text - as described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-creating-a-manpage/), then you either need an installer to put it in /usr/local/share/man (or other man directory), or else you could provide a --help option to your script that loads the man page directly.

Example page:

```
.\" Manpage for nuseradd.
.\" Contact vivek@nixcraft.net.in to correct errors or typos.
.TH man 8 "06 May 2010" "1.0" "nuseradd man page"
.SH NAME
nuseradd \- create a new LDAP user
.SH SYNOPSIS
nuseradd [USERNAME]
.SH DESCRIPTION
nuseradd is high level shell program for adding users to LDAP server.  On Debian, administrators should usually use nuseradd.debian(8) instead.
.SH OPTIONS
The nuseradd does not take any options. However, you can supply username.
.SH SEE ALSO
useradd(8), passwd(5), nuseradd.debian(8)
.SH BUGS
No known bugs.
.SH AUTHOR
Vivek Gite (vivek@nixcraft.net.in)
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy !! Will try using it now.Hope it works on server machine.

Comment: I am getting the following error:
No manual entry for nuseradd

Comment: @user2377245: where did you place the manual page?  It would need to go in `/usr/local/share/man/man1` directory as `nuseradd.1`, or a similar location.  If you're on Linux and have `nuseradd` in `$HOME/bin`, then `man` may automatically look in `$HOME/bin/man/man1` or `$HOME/man/man1` for the manual page.  For other versions of Unix, look at `man man` to see where it looks for manual pages.

Comment: Thanks Dude am able to view it now. /usr/local/share/man/man1 Resolved it :)

Comment: But unable to use the same in remote server as I dnt have access to write :(